# how to access Netty ChannelHandlerContext (or similar) within Jersey Resources

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, netty

I am using Jersey + Netty as my framework for providing a RESTful API.

I would like to be able to access the [ChannelHandlerContext](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html), [Channel](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html) (or similar), via a mechanism such as @Context as part of Resource methods - use cases include remote IP addresses. Similar to [HttpHeaders](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html) and others.

Using @Context currently resources in the ChannelHandlerContext being null, therefore I am assuming something either doesn't exist (i.e. i have to write it?) or isn't setup to handle the injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible in 2.28 as SecurityContext may be cast to NettySecurityContext which has a getNettyContext() method.